# Swift Segue programmatically takes long time

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Using Swift an Xcode 6.4, I am creating an login system. It works good. I obtain XML data from a website and check if the user is logged.

```
    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

    if elementName == "isLoggedIn" {
        if elementValue == "true" {
            success = true
            println(success)
            println("IS HERE")
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginIsOk", sender: nil)

        }else if elementValue == "false"{
            success = false
            println(success)
        }
        elementValue = nil
    }  
}
```

When I run the APP, takes 1 second to "println("IS HERE")". 
So I assume.

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginIsOk", sender: nil)
```

is executed after that. But it takes like 5 seconds to show the other ViewController.

If I do the same, but inside an UIButton for example, after click on it, its show the second ViewController instantly.

Any idea why is taking so long inside the func parser? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try putting it inside a different thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
  self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginIsOk", sender: nil)
})
```

All UI calls should be placed in the main thread for precisely this reason - we want the UI to be snappy!

Comment: Thanks @Mark it works perfectly. Now I do not understand why this methods is not running in the main thread.

Comment: This is a really interesting read which gives you a bit of insight to threads/concurrency in iOS and OS X https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign/ConcurrencyandApplicationDesign.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH100-SW1